# Spring Boot application gives 404 when deployed to Tomcat but works with embedded server

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

Guided by [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), I'm creating a Spring Boot web application that I can run using both the embedded Tomcat instance as well as on a standalone Tomcat 8 server.

The application works as expected when executed as `java -jar adminpage.war` and I see the expected outcome when I visit `http://localhost:8080/table`. However, when I deploy to a Tomcat 8 server (by dropping `adminpage.war` into the `webapps` directory), I get a 404 error when I visit `https://myserver/adminpage/table`.

The `catelina.log` and `localhost.log` files contain nothing helpful on the Tomcat server.

Can anyone suggest where I've made a misconfiguration? I've not had the same problems in the past when deploying RESTful services with Spring Boot, but this is my first foray into a web application.

My application files:

`src/main/java/com/.../Application.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

`src/main/java/com/.../MainController.java`

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/table")
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Fooballs");
        return "table";
    }
}
```

`src/main/resources/templates/table.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>adminpage</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>


  <build>
    <finalName>adminpage</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does your application contains web.xml?

Comment: @SergeyBespalov I don't think it needs one with Spring Boot. See my answer below - I had forgotten to adjust my `Application.java` file.

Comment: you're right it's not necessary, but still can be used with Spring Boot

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I had forgotten to tweak my `Application.java` file to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override the `configure` method.

Corrected file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
      return builder.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```

Hat tip to https://mtdevuk.com/2015/07/16/how-to-make-a-spring-boot-jar-into-a-war-to-deploy-on-tomcat/ for pointing out my mistake.

More info at [Create a deployable war file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) in Spring Boot Official docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot but now the class is depricated ;)

Comment: mayank, can you tell the latest way?

Answer (score 19):

As of August 2021 .
If anyone facing this issue in Tomcat 10 server, just read in the below post that Spring boot won't work in Tomcat 10.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22414

I had faced this issue and switching to an previous version, which resolved the problem.

Comment: Very important information, was struggling for a while, thanks Dipu!

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 9 and still facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've wasted several hours of my life with this Tomcat BS

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading Tomcat from version 10 to 9 did the trick for me.
Update January 2022, apparently tomcat 10 still does not support spring-boot.
As mentioned by Dipu over here,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68917349/13294956

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone having same problem while using sprint boot in the IntelliJ community edition. You just need to put your main class in the main package (com.xyx) don't put it in any subpackage which is created inside com.xyx.

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting dieter's answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714904/after-deployment-of-war-to-tomcat-docker-container-always-getting-404):

> You war file name is priz-0.5.war. So the context name is also priz-0.5. You have to call for example http://localhost:8080/priz-0.5
>
> If you want to call it like http://localhost:8080/ just rename the war-File to ROOT.war

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I had compiled the app for java 11, while my server was running java 8. Once I upgraded to java 11 it worked fine. It was tricky because I there was absolutely nothing in Tomcats log that indicated that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the route in the controller annotation, something like this:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Spring boot wasn't work with tomcat 10. I changed for 9 version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but everything was fine with my SpringBootConfiguration
I finally found out why I had a 404

I just removed maven-dependency-plugin in build->plugin from my pom.xml

```
<!--
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
-->
```

This removal allowed me to finally test my war file on a tomcat9 with success and still allow me to test via mvnw

May this help someone