# After deployment of WAR to tomcat docker container always getting 404

Tags: tomcat, docker, war

I have a grails app, that already runs and was deployed to AWS through Elastic Beanstalk on Tomcat8 Jre8.

I am now trying to deploy it on multi-docker environment and I have quite weird behavior.

I am using `tomcat:8.0-jre8` (https://hub.docker.com/r/library/tomcat/) as an image for container, and the deployment on that image is pretty simple, by putting a war file in `<tomcat_home>/webapps`. Also, I am mapping port `8080` to the outside world. So, related portion of docker-compose look like this:

```
api:
  image: tomcat:8.0-jre8
  container_name: api
  volumes:
    - ./deployment/api:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
  external_links:
    - mysql:mysql
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

Based on the logs, the app is getting deployed successfully, and even liquibase migrations are getting applied:

```
21-Nov-2016 07:11:03.671 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/priz-0.5.war
21-Nov-2016 07:12:12.496 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2016-11-21T07:13:38.397268676Z 
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
2016-11-21T07:13:40.215275700Z 
2016-11-21T07:13:40.777432843Z 
Configuring Spring Security REST 2.0.0.M2...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST
2016-11-21T07:13:41.515464956Z 
INFO 11/21/16 7:14 AM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 11/21/16 7:14 AM: liquibase: Reading from priz.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 11/21/16 7:14 AM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
21-Nov-2016 07:15:09.019 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/priz-0.5.war has finished in 245,345 ms
21-Nov-2016 07:15:09.026 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
21-Nov-2016 07:15:09.036 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
21-Nov-2016 07:15:09.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 245425 ms
```

However, when I am trying to access ANY one of the existing endpoints, I am getting 404 back.

Now, also based on the logs, the request is actually hitting the server:

```
==> ./logs/localhost_access_log.2016-11-21.txt <==
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016:07:15:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016:07:15:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016:07:16:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016:07:17:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016:07:17:07 +0000] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016:07:28:24 +0000] "GET /api/user/register HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016:07:28:46 +0000] "POST /api/user/register HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

How do I even approach this problem how to debug it? What am I missing? 
There is nothing special in the logs.

Also, I tried different versions of tomcat, including the exact one that runs on AWS EBS. 
Also, tried proxing the request through nginx, same result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You war file name is `priz-0.5.war`. So the context name is also `priz-0.5`. 
You have to call for example `http://localhost:8080/priz-0.5`

If you want to call it like `http://localhost:8080/` just rename the war-File to `ROOT.war`

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that! How do I change that to respond to root? Or, at least, ho do I make it consistent between versions? Also, why my previous deployment didn't require that, and if I start the app through `run-app` I can use it without the context.

Comment: Stuck for two days in this.. thanks a lot.