# Spring Boot REST API war file generating 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, war

I have a REST API developed with Spring Boot.

If I run it from the IDE it works fine.

For instance, the following url returns the correct json.

```
http://localhost:8080/xyz
```

Now I want to deploy the app.

Generated a war file and deployed it locally to:

C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.43\webapps

Closed the IDE.

Then started Tomcat and accessed the following url again.

```
http://localhost:8080/xyz
```

I'm getting a HTTP 404 error.

What could be the reason?

Tomcat is starting correctly.

http://localhost:8080 correctly opens tomcat main page.

It is also correctly generating the app folder under \webapps.

Comment: ```404``` mostly means the path to the target file is incorrect 
please check whether if the paths are correct or not

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567434/spring-boot-application-gives-404-when-deployed-to-tomcat-but-works-with-embedde[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567434/spring-boot-application-gives-404-when-deployed-to-tomcat-but-works-with-embedde)

Comment: Rename war file with ROOT.war

Comment: @Deviprasad Sharma I'm accessing it using the same path that works when running the app from the IDE (http://localhost:8080/xyz).So what could be wrong with the path? Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: @Alien Tried renaming to ROOT.war. Didn't work. Same 404 error.

Comment: Why bother deploying and not run the war (or better the jar)? How do you create the war file? Also the url is `http://localhost:8080/<name-of-war/xyz` unless `/xyz` is due to setting `server.servlet.` properties (as those don't apply when deploying).

Comment: spring-boot serves the (web) application (by default) on `localhost:8080` ..a web container has its own rules... and the default "context" (in e.g. tomcat) is `localhost:8080/app`*when* there is an `app.war` (or extracted folder `app`) in "webapps".

Comment: @M. Deinum You are correct. That was the issue. Needed to add the app name in the url. Thank you.

Comment: @xerx593 You are correct. That was the issue. Needed to add the app name in the url. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deploying your war file a folder will be generated with same name of war file.
So the Url will be `http://localhost:8080/<war_file_name>/xyz`

Comment: Correct. Now it worked. This was the problem. Just checked the answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @jkfe W e l c o m e.

Answer (score 0):

When you run with your Ide its run only Enbibed tomcat and its only run your app that why you don't need that war file name as root path. But when  run your app extremal tomcat it's need to use War File name as root of your app because here root is tomcat container that run different war and each war root path its file name. That's why <war_file_name> is needed before your path.

> http://localhost:8080/<war_file_name>/xyz