# Spring Data JPA App With MySQL DB Postman Returns 404 On Any Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman

I am trying to build a Spring Boot API using Spring Data JPA, Spring Web, and MySQL. I've done everything I am supposed to, it connects to the database, but Postman ALWAYS returns 404, "Not Found" error, no matter what I try. Spring Boot initializes succcesfully:

```
[0;39m [36mc.cg.TestProject.TestProjectApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting TestProjectApplication using Java 17.0.3 on LNAR-5CG1514NF9 with PID 21336 (C:\Users\********\OneDrive - *********\Desktop\Orientation\TestProject\target\classes started by ******** in C:\Users\********\OneDrive - *********\Desktop\Orientation\TestProject)
[0;39m [36mc.cg.TestProject.TestProjectApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 80 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
[0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 1111 (http)
[0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
[0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 974 ms
[0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
[0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
[0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[0;39m [36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 1111 (http) with context path ''
[0;39m [36mc.cg.TestProject.TestProjectApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started TestProjectApplication in 2.839 seconds (JVM running for 3.873)
[0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

My project is divided into 5 packages: main class package(TestProject), POJOs, controllers, services, and repositories. I currently one have one, simple table I'm working with that stores a user's name, and "password"  This is my main class called TestProjectApplication:

```
@EntityScan("com.cg.POJOs")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.cg.repositories")
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
```

My User POJO, and the UserRepo repository:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    public User() {}
    public User(int id, String name, String password)
    {
        super(); //OPTIONAL?
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }
...Getters, Setters, toString
```

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {
   
}
```

These have been largely unchanged, as they are pretty standard. Where it gets a little more confusing, and I have tried every type of and combination of Spring Boot annotations to no avail, is my UserServices interface, the UserServicesImpl implementation, and the UserController.

UserServices and UserServicesImpl:

```
#UserServices:
import java.util.List;
public interface UserServices {
    
    // Save operation
    User saveUser(User user);
  
    // Read operation
    List<User> fetchUserList();
  
    // Update operation
    User updateUser(User user, int userId);
  
    // Delete operation
    void deleteUserById(int userId);
}

#userServicesImpl:
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserServicesImpl implements UserServices{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> fetchUserList() {
        return (List<User>)userRepo.findAll();
    }

...updateUser(User user), deleteUserById(int id) are implemented.
```

And finally my controller class with a few test operations:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired 
    private UserServices userServices;

    // Save operation
    @PostMapping("/users")
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User department)
    {
        return userServices.saveUser(department);
    }
  
    // Read operation
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> fetchUserList()
    {
        return userServices.fetchUserList();
    }
    
    // Read operation
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public List<User> fetchUsers()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new User(12, "Carlos","123123"),
                new User(2, "donald","123456")
        );
    }
```

ALL requests I make, simply return a 404 "Not Found" error. An example request would be "GET http://localhost:1111/test". The last bit of information I could possibly show that might show my mistake, is my application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port = 1111
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Any ideas as to why it's not working would be greatly appreciated! Using Spring Boot 2.7.5 with Java 11 on the Spring Tool Suite IDE.

Comment: in your logs you don't see any error ?

Comment: In the IDE? Nope. Just what you see the about the dispatcherServlet. Before i try a request, that's not there. So something is going through.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring that your SpringBootApplication implementation extends SpringBootServletInitializer.

```
@EntityScan("com.cg.POJOs")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.cg.repositories")
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestProjectApplication extends 
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[This sort of explains why that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567434/spring-boot-application-gives-404-when-deployed-to-tomcat-but-works-with-embedde)

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being my file structure. My main class was located under com.x.a, meanwhile my other classes were in their own packages (com.x.b, com.x.c, etc.). The issue stemmed from the main class not being in the parent package. Unfortunately, the *only* thing I didn’t share in my post was my file structure, so the question was ultimately incomplete as my code ended up being ok.